# EM algorithm for non-Gaussian mixture

Tags: algorithm, matlab

In Matlab, I have been using the EM_GM function to estimate PDF weights and parameters for a mixture of lognormal (or otherwise skewed) distributions.  Even though the overall mixture is highly skewed (just like its component PDFs), the EM_GM function fits normal PDFs to the mixture pretty well.

Nonetheless, I would like to see what it looks like to fit lognormal PDFs to the mixture.  I appreciate it if someone can give me some tips on how to modify the EM_GM code to obtain mixture weights and parameters for lognormal components, or any non-Gaussian components for that matter.

EM_GM can be found here:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8636-emgm

Thanks

Comment: It may be worth asking the same question here too http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't know exactly how that code does its work, but chances are you will have to derive new M-step update rules. [This PDF](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.867/wiki/images/b/b5/Em_tutorial.pdf) has some nice explanation and examples of how to do this for uni/multivariate Gaussian distros as well as a simple topic model.